# getting Main.java:24: error: ';' expected on IdeOne

Tags: java

Here is a function i wrote, can't find the error . Help needed.Thanks in advance. double entropy(Node a) is the 24th line

```
double entropy(Node a)
{
    double a1=0,a2=0,a3=0,a4=0,sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<(a.data).size;i++)
    {
        int x=test[a.data[i]][a.pos];
        if(x==0)
            a1++;
        else if(x==1)
            a2++;
        else if(x==2)
            a3++;
        else if(x==3)
            a4++;
    }

    double total=a1+a2+a3+a4;
    sum+=-(a1/total)*(math.log(a1/total))-(a2/total)*(math.log(a2/total))-(a3/total)*(math.log(a3/total))-(a4/total)*(math.log(a4/total));
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the `24`th one?

Comment: sorry, double entropy(Node a) was the 24th ...i just posted the method

Comment: please post the whole code

Comment: That almost definitely means that the line _previous_ to that line had the error in it; the compiler thought it was something that should end in a simicolon, and it didn't (instead, it started with "double"). You're probably missing a semicolon, and possibly a closing curly brace, before it.

Comment: Also, `a.data.size` should be `a.data.length`, assuming that `a.data` is an array of some kind (which it would have to be, for `a.data[i]` to compile).